# How to do substring in HTBasic (TransEra)?

Tags: basic

I'm looking for the funtion to extract first 5 chars (substr in php) from a string in HTBasic

For example I want to extract "files" from the string "files zzz"

Comment: it depends on which BASIC you are using, but i remember that `LEFT$`  did the job: https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/LEFT$

Comment: I'm using HTBasic from TransEra but i will look at this function

Comment: I looked at the porting guide and you have the answer down if u are interested ! Thank's for the help buddy!

Answer (score 1):

To extract first 5 chars of a string var named X for example :

```
X$[1;5]
```